# Using :focus to style outer div?

Tags: css, focus, stylesheet

When I begin writing text in the textarea, I want the outer div, with a class box, to have its border turned solid instead of dashed, but somehow the :focus doesn't apply in this case. If it works with :active, how come it doesn't work with :focus?

Any ideas why?

(Note. I want the DIV's border to turn solid, NOT the textareas)

```
div.box
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: thin dashed black;
}

div.box:focus{
    border: thin solid black;
}

<div class="box">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with focus because the DIV will not have focus, only the TextArea will. I would image a DIV cannot have focus anyway as it is a non-selectable element

Comment: You'd need to use JavaScript to achieve this; as while the div can take focus the textarea will immediately take it back if it's clicked. [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2yyGU/); clicking outside the `textarea` will change the borders of the `div`, but activating the `textarea` steals focus back.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

While this can't be achieved with CSS/HTML alone, it can be achieved with JavaScript (without need of a library):

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

for (i=0;i<textareas.length;i++){
    // you can omit the 'if' if you want to style the parent node regardless of its
    // element type
    if (textareas[i].parentNode.tagName.toString().toLowerCase() == 'div') {
        textareas[i].onfocus = function(){
            this.parentNode.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        }
        textareas[i].onblur = function(){
            this.parentNode.style.borderStyle = 'dashed';
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2yyGU/1/).

Incidentally, with a library, such as jQuery, the above could be condensed down to:

```
$('textarea').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).parent('div').css('border-style','solid');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        $(this).parent('div').css('border-style','dashed');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2yyGU/2/).

References:

- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onfocus).
- [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onblur).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode).
- [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName).
- [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).
- [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).
- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer (especially one which doesn't need jQuery)

Comment: No longer the most efficient answer with the introduction of :focus-within pseudo-element!

Comment: this is a great answer and I think still effective since :focus-within is still currently a working draft. This was exactly what I needed. thank you.

Answer (score 187):

Other posters have already explained why the `:focus` pseudo class is insufficient, but finally there is a CSS-based standard solution.

CSS Selectors Level 4 defines a new pseudo class:

### [:focus-within](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-within-pseudo)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within):

> The `:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class matches any element that the `:focus`
>   pseudo-class matches or that has a descendant that the `:focus`
>   pseudo-class matches.  (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)

So now with the `:focus-within` pseudo class - styling the outer div when the `textarea` gets clicked becomes trivial.

```
.box:focus-within {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px dashed red;
}

.box:focus-within {
    border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>The outer box border changes when the textarea gets focus.</p>
<div class="box">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>
</div>
```

**[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/jweZPN)**

**NB:** [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within) : Chrome (60+), Firefox and Safari

Comment: Just want to mention that the tabindex is still needed, when there is a mix of static elements (div, span, etc.), and input elements inside the outer div, and the focus outline is needed even when one of the inner static elements is clicked.

Answer (score 91):

`DIV` elements can get focus if set the `tabindex` attribute. Here is the working example.

```css
#focus-example > .extra {
  display: none;
}
#focus-example:focus > .extra {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="focus-example" tabindex="0">
  <div>Focus me!</div>
  <div class="extra">Hooray!</div>
</div>
```

For more information about `focus` and `blur`, you can check out [this article](http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/01/onfocus-and-onblur-for-divs-in-fx/).

**Update:**
And here is another example using `focus` to create a `menu`.

```css
#toggleMenu:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button:focus + .menu {
  display: block;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu:focus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggleMenu" tabindex="0">
  <button type="button">Menu</button>
  <ul class="menu" tabindex="1">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Me</li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @NamanSood I've included the code to my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Is this cross-browser hack?

Comment: @jayarjo It works for me. Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu, ver. 49.0

Comment: It works when you don't have an input. If you click the non-input dom in the div, it works. If you click the input dom in the div, the input dom will capture your focus event and stop pop out.

Answer (score 6):

**focus-within**

```
.box:focus-within {
  background: cyan;
}
```

[read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

Answer (score 5):

This can now be achieve through the css method `:focus-within` as examplified in this post: [http://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/05/14/focus-within.html](http://CSS%20-%20Focus:within)

```css
/*
  A normal (though ugly) focus
  pseudo-class.  Any element that
  can receive focus within the
  .my-element parent will receive
  a yellow background.
*/
.my-element *:focus {
  background: yellow !important;
  color: #000;
}

/*
  The :focus-within pseudo-class
  will NOT style the elements within
  the .my-element selector, like the
  normal :focus above, but will
  style the .my-element container
  when its focusable children
  receive focus.
*/
.my-element:focus-within {
  outline: 3px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element">
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://scottohara.me">
      My Website
    </a>
  </p>

  <label for="wut_email">
    Your email:
  </label>
  <input type="email" id="wut_email" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes):

> The `:focus` pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus (accepts keyboard events or other forms of text input).

The `<div>` does not accept input, so it cannot have `:focus`. Furthermore, CSS does not allow you to set styles on an element based on targeting its descendants. So you can't really do this unless you are willing to use JavaScript.

Comment: Note that a `<div>` can get focus if you set the `contenteditable="true"` attribute. But in that case that's probably not the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simple use JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div .FormRow").focusin(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
    $(this).css("border", "3px solid #555");
  });
  $("div .FormRow").focusout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    $(this).css("border", "0px solid #555");
  });
});
```

```css
    .FormRow {
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="border: 0px solid black;padding:10px;">
    <div class="FormRow">
      First Name:
      <input type="text">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="FormRow">
      Last Name:
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><strong><em>Click an input field to get focus.</em></strong>
    </li>
    <li><strong><em>Click outside an input field to lose focus.</em></strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And more simplest, **don't use jquery**, there is nice example, solution, by @DavidThomas ... what is the point loading jquery file approx. 77-94kB for something like this, and much more...

Comment: @nelek, if you anyway use jQuery, that's a great solution, more robust too (cross browser without spending forever to debug on browsers you don't even have access to!)

Answer (score 2):

You can tab between div tags. Just add a tab index to the div. It's best to use jQuery and CSS classes to solve this problem. Here's a working sample tested in IE, Firefox, and Chrome (Latest versions... didn't test older).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var divParentIdFocus;
            var divParentIdUnfocus = null;

            $(document).ready(function() {              

                    $("div").focus(function() {
                        //$(this).attr("class", "highlight");
                        var curDivId = $(this).attr("id");

                        // This Check needs to be performed when/if div regains focus
                        // from child element.
                        if (divParentIdFocus != curDivId){
                            divParentIdUnfocus = divParentIdFocus;
                            divParentIdFocus = curDivId;
                            refreshHighlight();
                        }

                        divParentIdFocus = curDivId;
                    });


                    $("textarea").focus(function(){
                        var curDivId = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");

                        if(divParentIdFocus != curDivId){
                            divParentIdUnfocus = divParentIdFocus;
                            divParentIdFocus = curDivId;
                            refreshHighlight();
                        }
                    });

                    $("#div1").focus();
            });

            function refreshHighlight()
            {
                if(divParentIdUnfocus != null){
                    $("#" +divParentIdUnfocus).attr("class", "noHighlight");
                    divParentIdUnfocus = null;
                }

                $("#" + divParentIdFocus).attr("class", "highlight");
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .highlight{
                background-color:blue;
                border: 3px solid black;
                font-weight:bold;
                color: white;
            }
            .noHighlight{           
            }
            div, h1,textarea, select { outline: none; }

        </style>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id = "div1" tabindex="100">
            <h1>Div 1</h1> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="101">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="102">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="103">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="104">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
        </div>
        <div id = "div2" tabindex="200">
            <h1>Div 2</h1> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="201">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="202">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="203">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="204">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
        </div>
        <div id = "div3" tabindex="300">
            <h1>Div 3</h1> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="301">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="302">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="303">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="304">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
        </div>
        <div id = "div4" tabindex="400">
            <h1>Div 4</h1> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="401">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="402">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="403">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
            <textarea rows="2" cols="25" tabindex="404">~Your Text Here~</textarea> <br />
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you have to use javascript to travel up the dom.

Something like this:

```
$("textarea:focus").parent().attr("border", "thin solid black");
```

you'll need the jQuery libraries loaded as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `**:focus-within**` to give style to outer `div` whenever an inner element is focused.

Another way to do that is to add `**tabIndex**` to a `div`. Then you can easily give `**:focus**` to just a `div`.