# setting focus css property to a div

Tags: html, css, properties, focus

I created a div containing a dropdown select box. I have set focus to the div by giving `tabindex="0"`. When the div is focused, the border outline is not having rounded corners just as the dropdown box has. How do I change the css property of div when focused.

```
<div id="test" tabindex="0" class="blablabla">
```

Tried adding css properties by

```
div#test: focus {
    background: white;
    outline: none;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: The focus styles need to be on the base style that you want (probably class 'blablabla')

Comment: Remove space before focus, `div#test:focus`.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#test: focus {
```

should be

```
div#test:focus {
```

---

`focus` on a `div` is hacky though. See this:

[Using :focus to style outer div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876283/using-focus-to-style-outer-div)