# Focus styling is not working correctly in a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

**Problem:**

I have created a react application there I am creating a custom search box.

```
<div className="search-box">
  <Row>
    <div className="search-box-icon">
      <i className="fas fa-search" />
    </div>
    <input
      className="search-input"
      placeholder="search in listbox"
    />
  </Row>
</div>
```

This is my css stylings.

```
.search-box-icon {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.search-input {
  border: none;
}

.search-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box:focus {
  outline-color: #53c9fc;
  outline-width: 2px;
}
```

What I need to do is add an outline to search-box div when someone starts to type something on the textbox. The things I have done does not seem to be work. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Your code works.Can you share  your component.This is working sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/ykrn4883kx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using :focus to style outer div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876283/using-focus-to-style-outer-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this using css/html without `tabindex` and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#Accessibility_concerns):

> Avoid using the `tabindex` attribute in conjunction with non-interactive content to make something intended to be interactive focusable by keyboard input. An example of this would be using an `<div>` element to describe a button, instead of the `<button>` element.

[and w3 says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)

> The content should be semantically described using interactive elements (`<a>`, `<button>`, `<details>`, `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc.) instead.

So the best practice for this is using `addEventListener()` in `JavaScript`, But if you want to use `tabindex` don't forget to add `tabindex` to inner html content.

#### Another solution

You don't have to use `tabindex` if you just want to change the `div` border.
you can use `:focus-within` and just change the border.

```css
.search-box {
  margin-left: 1%;
  outline: red;
  border: 1px solid #fc3;
}

.search-input {
  border: none;
}

.search-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.search-box:focus-within {
  border: 2px solid #53c9fc;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <Row>
    <div class="search-box-icon">
    </div>
    <input
      class="search-input"
      placeholder="search in listbox"
    />
  </Row>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do focus on a `div` tag without `tabindex`.

```
<div 
  className="search-box" 
  tabIndex="1" // add this line
>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: @dwp Don't mention it ;)

Comment: @dwp This isn't a good practice to do this, it breaks the accessibility, please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55087153/5721245